# Is it possible to set one AWS Cloudwatch Alarm for multiple Metrics on an API Gateway using AWS CDK?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-cdk

Is it possible to set a single ***Cloudwatch*** ***Alarm*** for an ***API*** ***Gateway*** so that it should listen out for ***4xx*** AND ***5xx*** errors?

My goal is that the alarm should have a threshold of say 10 errors in 5 minutes, and it should be triggered by either of these two errors.

So if there are five ***4xx*** errors and five ***5xx*** errors it should go into alarm.

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, is this good practice or is it better to have 2 alarms, one for each, ***4xx*** and ***5xx***?
3. I'm using **aws cdk for python**, so as a bonus I'd appreciate if you can answer to that direction.

Thanks